# How to put ASP.NET website in maintenace mode but should remain online

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm aware of **app.offline.htm** feature to take a site down, which is awesome by the way, but I would need a way where I can show a "under maintenance" site to the public but the site should remain online (which means available to a certain group of people) so I can adapt the backend and so on.

What is the recommended way of doing this?

*FYI: I have total control over the server*

Comment: Define "stay online".

Comment: Added further description describing ONLINE

Comment: There would be no builtin support and as the developer you are supposed to build your own web farm to achieve high availability.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using role based permissions on your site (a.k.a. requiring a login, active directroy etc...) then if the user has the role\permissions that you require, then they can see what portion of the site you want them to see while you develop your backend. Else, they just get a "Under maintenance" page. But this could be dependent on a roles tables in your backend which you may not have developed yet, so this approach would not work for you.

Out side of authenticating and authorizing a user, I am not sure how you allow certain users and not others to see portions of your web site while you work on your backend.